# Unity3D: Smooth Interaction When Loading Asset Via Network?

Tags: multithreading, performance, rendering, unity-game-engine

I'm making a networked computer game using Unity3D version 3.x on Mac. I have a game client and a game server. Whenever data arrives at the client from the server, the client would freeze for a little bit (~0.5 seconds), render the new data, and then continue. Is there any way I can optimize my game so that incoming data does not affect user's interaction with the game client?

Here's what I'm doing now:

1. I created a new thread to pull data from the server.
2. When the data arrives I put it in a buffer which is protected by a mutual exclusion lock.
3. In the Unity thread, on every frame, I check if the buffer is empty. If it is not empty, I wait on the mutual exclusion lock for permission to process the data. Once I got the permission, I parse the data and render it.

I'm doing this because Unity does not allow me to create new `GameObject`s in the network thread that I created. But I wonder if there's anything I can do to optimize user experience.

Comment: You should use the WWW class to retrieve things off the network within unity, it will help you with optimization then.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderBrevig, unfortunately the `WWW` class is not an option for me. For research purpose of this project, I have to do the networking part on my own, instead of relying on what Unity gives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to first profile to know the source of the freezing, i.e. is it due to waiting on the lock? due to parsing? due to GameObject instantiation? all three?

[Unity Profiler (Pro only)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Profiler.html)

General solutions:

- If the pause is due to the lock, try splitting up your buffering into
  different bins, so that the main thread can access the next non-empty
  bin without having to acquire lock, or at least such a coarse-grained lock.
- If parsing is the slowdown, you can still do all of that in a
  background thread. Perform as much as you possibly can before you finally must instantiate GameObjects.
- If it's the final step of instantiating GameObjects, then you
  can try to preinstantiate objects you expect, simply reconfiguring
  them upon new network data; or divide up the instantation
  process into separate, incremental phases, with unnoticeably small
  pauses, e.g. a root node first, then next phase its children, and so on, until fully reconstructed.

Comment: Thanks! I profiled my game and found that the instantiating gameobject part takes up to 90% of time. Within the instantiating job, `Mesh.Bake Scaled Mesh PhysX CollisionData` is taking up 85.7% of time...